# How to use text/ng-template script section in jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsfiddle

I'm trying to create a jsfiddle which uses AngularJS to show two calendar controls:

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/pe4sfex6/10/

My code works locally.

I've copied everything up to jsfiddle, but it seems that my method of including the template code via a script tag isn't working:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="calendarTemplate">
    <div class="header">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left" ng-click="previous()"></i>
        <span>{{month.format("MMMM, YYYY")}}</span>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right" ng-click="next()"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="week names">
        <span class="day">Sun</span>
        <span class="day">Mon</span>
        <span class="day">Tue</span>
        <span class="day">Wed</span>
        <span class="day">Thu</span>
        <span class="day">Fri</span>
        <span class="day">Sat</span>
    </div>
    <div class="week" ng-repeat="week in weeks">
        <span class="day" ng-class="{ today: day.isToday, 'different-month': !day.isCurrentMonth, selected: day.date.isSame(selected) }" ng-click="select(day)" ng-repeat="day in week.days">{{day.number}}</span>
    </div>
</script>
```

I did it this way, of course, because I can't access a file on jsfiddle, or is there a way to do this on jsfiddle:

```
templateUrl: "templates/calendarTemplate.html",
```

If not, how can I get jsfiddle to process the text/ng-template script the way it does locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- select "no wrap - in `<head>`" under **Frameworks & Extensions**
- add the body tag `<body ng-app="demo">` under **Fiddle Options**

Here's the [updated Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/pe4sfex6/12/)

#### Explanation

In your JSfiddle the option **onDomReady** is selected, this means that the Javascript code gets wrapped in an `onDomReady` window event (see [frameworks and extensions](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#frameworks-and-extensions) in the JSfiddle documentation). In order to allow AngularJS to see the app before the DOM is fully loaded, select a "no wrap" option (in `<head>` or in `<body>`).

Next you need is to change the `body` tag in the [JSfiddle options](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-options). This is because the [directive `ng-app`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) used to auto-bootstrap an AngularJS application

> is typically placed near the root element of the page - e.g. on the
>   `<body>` or `<html>` tags